# Method Not Allowed Error when calling an existing endpoint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I get this error:

```
Method Not Allowed: /api/v1/auth/users/student/submission/
"POST /api/v1/auth/users/student/submission/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41
```

when accessing the endpoint to one of my Django apps modelviewset (Submission).

Below is the setup;

1. views

   ```
   class SubmissionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       serializer_class = SubmissionSerializer
       queryset = Submission.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
       permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.save(student=self.request.user)
   ```
2. URLs

   ```
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register("admin/courses", views.AdminCourseViewSet)
    router.register("student/courses", views.StudentCourseViewSet)
    router.register("student/submission", views.SubmissionViewSet)

    urlpatterns = [
      path("users/", include(router.urls)),
    ]
   ```
3. Serializer

   ```
    class SubmissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = serializers.UUIDField()
    course = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    date_submitted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = [
          "id",
          "project",
          "course",
          "submission_link",
          "status",
          "date_submitted",
          "student_comments",
          "mentor_comments",
         ]
         read_only_fields = ["id","course", "status", "date_submitted"]

    def get_course(self, instance):
        return instance.project.course.title

    def get_date_submitted(self, instance):
        return instance.date_submitted.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
   ```
4. Models

   ```
    class Submission(TimeStampedUUIDModel):
        class STATUS(models.TextChoices):
        """
         Choices for the project
        """

        REVIEWED = "Reviewed", _("Reviewed")
        PENDING = "Pending", _("Pending")
        NOT_SUBMITTED = "Not_Submitted", _("Not_Submitted")

        student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        submission_link = models.URLField()
        status = models.CharField(
            verbose_name=_("Project Review Status"),
            choices=STATUS.choices,
            default=STATUS.NOT_SUBMITTED,
            max_length=20)
        date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        student_comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
        mentor_comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.student.first_name} {self.student.last_name} 
            {self.project.project_title} submission."
   ```

I want to understand what I am doing wrong as I have exhausted all possibilities to get it work.
django version: 4.1.13
django-rest-framework: 3.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'permission_classes' from the view which belongs to the submission URL. If it works then the reason is that the application wants an authenticated user to access the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here:

Can you try using [`SimpleRouter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) instead?

Using [`DefaultRouter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) adds handling that you probably don't want or expect, but the naming *really* makes it sound like the "Default" one!

You can also try calling `/api/v1/auth/users/student/submission/` with `GET` (just open it in a browser), and see what it returns.  If it is a list of the various actions then you know you hit the `DefaultRouter`'s default page.